# How to know the run command that vscode creates from launch.json?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a launch.json like below:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["server"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I launch it using the debug view on VScode it works fine but I need to change the `program` attribute to relative path of the respective file from my workspace location, strange behaviour is observed, other components in the same package start throwing `undefined` func error. Probably something goes wrong with current working dir or go module setup.

In order to investigate further, I need to know the command that is generated from this launch.json file. It should be something like `go run ...`
I have checked the output and debug console, both of them shows nothing about the launch command.

If you know how to see launch command, please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you do `go run ...` imports of the **same** packages won't work, since they are not linked to the file. You need to do `go build` and run the compiled binary. External imports which are import by the `import` keyword will work as expected.

Here's an example of `launch` config

```yaml
    "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch Package",
                "type": "go",
                "request": "launch",
                "mode": "auto",
                "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.go"
            }
        ]
    }
```

`${workspaceFolder}` is your root which will be replaced by full path when launched.

More on VSCode variables [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Edit: I just realised I answered a 3 years old question...

Answer (score -1):

You can find the generated command in Visual Studio Code's debug output. When you have started a debug session, open the Debug Console by clicking on the Debug Console icon in the View Bar or by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Y. The debug output will include the generated command line.